# How to add a rest of salary to each employee per MANAGER_ID using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem with case in topic. I would like to subtract a rest of between two amounts.

If there is a value > 0, then I want to add the rest per each employee partitioned by MANAGER_ID, but every one cent.

For instance: The rest is 0,04 $ and I have three employees as being led by the same manager. And I will select max value of employee ID and add 0,01$ to the record, the second one get 0,01$, next one 0,01$ and again the max value of employee ID get 0,01$ more, because If the rest is higher than count of employees with the same manager then It will cycle.

Another example is when we have 0,02$ rest and four employees, then only first two will get 0,01$ and  the last two 0,00$.

How to do it USING ONLY SQL? Without PL/SQL. I will be grateful for every help.

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_SCKOV_CASE
(MANAGER_ID NUMBER
,EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER
,AMOUNT NUMBER
,AMOUNT2 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (1,122,1053.21, 1053.23);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (1,123,1053.21, 1053.23);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (1,124,1053.21, 1053.23);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (1,125,1053.21, 1053.23);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (5,126,1229.87, 1229.92);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (5,127,1229.87, 1229.92);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (5,128,1229.87, 1229.92);
INSERT INTO TMP_SCKOV_CASE (MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, AMOUNT, AMOUNT2) VALUES (5,129,1229.87, 1229.92);

SELECT T.*, T.AMOUNT2-T.AMOUNT DIFF FROM TMP_SCKOV_CASE T
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Add some code please

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated by adding the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3c00368e3ea0cdaee987ddfb5595be5b)</sup>**

```
merge into tmp_sckov_case tgt
using (
  with 
    t1 as (
      select t.*, count(1) over (partition by manager_id) cnt, 
             floor(100*(t.amount2 - t.amount)/ count(1) over (partition by manager_id))/100 full_cent 
        from tmp_sckov_case t),
    t2 as (
      select t1.*, (amount2 - amount - cnt * full_cent) / .01 surplus, 
             row_number() over (partition by manager_id order by employee_id) rn
        from t1)
  select manager_id, employee_id, full_cent + case when rn <= surplus then .01 else 0 end rest 
    from t2) src
on (tgt.manager_id = src.manager_id and tgt.employee_id = src.employee_id)
when matched then update set amount = amount + rest
```

Subquery `t1` counts full cents which each employee should get, for id=1 it is 0, for id=5 it is 1. Subquery `t2` counts remaining cents. Last select assigns these cents using row_number().

Now we know amount for each worker and we put our query into `merge` as source data. In my dbfiddle you can see each part more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution based on maths quotient and mods.

```
select manager_id, employee_id
,.01 * quot + coalesce((case when rnk <= Remm and quot = 0 then .01
when rnk <= Remm and quot > 0 then .01 *remm
end),0) as value
from 
(select manager_id, employee_id, amount2, amount
, count(employee_id) over(partition by manager_id) tot_employee
, rank() over(partition by manager_id order by employee_id desc) as rnk
,floor(((Amount2-Amount)/.01) / (count(employee_id) over(partition by manager_id)) )  as Quot
,mod(((Amount2-Amount)/.01) , count(employee_id) over(partition by manager_id) ) as remm
from TMP_SCKOV_CASE
) a11
```